# Casting array of bytes in numpy to int32

Tags: python, numpy, casting

I have a numpy array A of two bytes which I want to combine into an int32. How do I do casting which combines array elements to create different datatype?

Comment: Example and expected result? Can you work with the data **before** it gets into an ndarray? If so, example of the raw data please. [mre]

Comment: I have.a packet I receive, I convert it to a numpy ubyte array. I want to slice sections of the array and combine them. For example A[0] is first 8 bits and A[1] is second 8 bits. So B = A[0]<<8+ A[1].

Comment: And you need to have it in an ndarray first? why doesn't your `B = A[0]<<8+ A[1]` solution work?

Comment: I guess this works, but I eventually want to cast it into a large structured array. With C you can just copy the memory location and cast. How to do with numpy?

Comment: `numpy` doesn't work that way.  How are you receiving the data?  If you are receiving a Python bytes array, like from a socket, then you can use the Python `array` or `struct` modules to have those bytes interpreted as halfwords.  That's the closest thing to a C-style reinterpret cast.

Comment: Show how you convert the packet. Have you tried a `int16` dtype?  `int32` is 4 bytes.  `dtype` can also have '<' or '>' to control endedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays can be 'viewed' with different dtypes, provided the byte counts are correct.

```
In [265]: arr = np.array([1,11], 'ubyte')
In [266]: arr
Out[266]: array([ 1, 11], dtype=uint8)
In [267]: arr.view('i2')
Out[267]: array([2817], dtype=int16)
In [268]: arr.view('>i2')                # with different endedness
Out[268]: array([267], dtype=int16)
In [269]: arr.view('uint16')
Out[269]: array([2817], dtype=uint16)
```

`int32` requires 4 bytes:

```
In [270]: arr.view('int32')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-270-4ab2a022f898>", line 1, in <module>
    arr.view('int32')
ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.
```

Similarly if the bytes were obtained from a bytestring

```
In [271]: astr = arr.tobytes()
In [272]: astr
Out[272]: b'\x01\x0b'
In [273]: np.frombuffer(astr, 'uint8')
Out[273]: array([ 1, 11], dtype=uint8)
In [274]: np.frombuffer(astr, 'uint16')
Out[274]: array([2817], dtype=uint16)
In [275]: np.frombuffer(astr, '<i2')
Out[275]: array([2817], dtype=int16)
In [276]: np.frombuffer(astr, '>i2')
Out[276]: array([267], dtype=int16)
```

view with a compound dtype

```
In [279]: arr.view('b')
Out[279]: array([ 1, 11], dtype=int8)
In [280]: arr.view('b,b')
Out[280]: array([(1, 11)], dtype=[('f0', 'i1'), ('f1', 'i1')])
```

Shape may need adjustment after such a view.

Comment: Thanks, the view function is what I was looking for. Lastly do you know if you can cast into a structured array all at once?

Comment: see my last edit